# Deploying Meteor with Forever

Tags: linux, meteor, deployment

I have attempting to deploy my meteor application for the very first time. I used the following instructions - [here](https://habrahabr.ru/post/279103/) (sorry for Russian, you can just read the lines of code). And after all the steps, I get this error.

localhost:31000 is what I set my MongoDB variable to be - `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:31000/meteor`

Can someone at please help me at least find a way in which I need to start digging?

```
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:31000]
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/concordls/public_html/dcmDeploy/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:213:1)
    at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:1)
    at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:102:1)
    at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (accounts_common.js:23:18)
    at new AccountsServer (accounts_server.js:16:5)
    at Package (globals_server.js:5:12)
    at /home/concordls/public_html/dcmDeploy/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1814:4
    - - - - -
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/concordls/public_html/dcmDeploy/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:74)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/concordls/public_html/dcmDeploy/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/concordls/public_html/dcmDeploy/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Script restart attempt #4
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should use [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up), It do exactly what you're trying to do without manual commands execution.

> **Production Quality Meteor Deployments**
>
> Meteor Up (mup for short) is a command line tool that allows you to deploy any Meteor app to your own server. It supports only Debian/Ubuntu flavours and Open Solaris at the moments.

[Deploying With Digital Ocean, Compose.io, and Meteor Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLGdXtZMmiI)

Comment: Will I be able to deploy my App if it was not originally made with Mup? The mup init command worries me.

Comment: @Alexey Sure mup init will just creates config files for mup (mup.json and settings.json)